# What/where is this large building with flags?

Tags: identify-this, architecture

I believe it is an American estate, because of the flags, but I don't know where.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM5cg.jpg)[image: large buildings]

Comment: I only think it is American because of the flag.

Comment: What flag? I do not see any American flag.

Comment: @NeanDerThal The flag at the top center of the building might be an American flag, but it's difficult to be sure as part of it seems to be obscured.

Comment: What's the story of this image?

Comment: I tried to identify the flags on the side, they do not match any of the state flags.. I thought that might be a good lead.

Answer (score 34):

This is the former Round Island House / Hotel Frontenac / The New Frontenac (with annex building) on Round Island near [Clayton, NY, United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clayton,_New_York). The New Frontenac existed from ca 1898 till 1911, when it burned down. For pics and more details on its history, see [Clayton's Historic Island Hotels by Rex Ennis](http://tilife.org/BackIssues/Archive/tabid/393/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/80/Claytons-Historic-Island-Hotels.aspx).

Some more pics of the former "New Frontenac":

[image: New Frontenac Hotel on Round Island, NY. From "Clayton's Historic Island Hotels" by Rex Ennis]

[image: New Frontenac Hotel on Round Island, NY. From Clayton Chamber of Commerce, https://www.1000islands-clayton.com/about/history/]

[image: New Frontenac Hotel on Round Island, NY. From "Did You Know? (1000 Islands Facts)" by Susan G. Smith, http://tilife.org/BackIssues/Archive/tabid/393/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/2108/Did-You-Know-1000-Islands-Facts.aspx]

Here's a map showing Round Island with the "New Frontenac":

[image: Map of Round Island, NY. From "Did You Know? (1000 Islands Facts)" by Susan G. Smith, http://tilife.org/BackIssues/Archive/tabid/393/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/2108/Did-You-Know-1000-Islands-Facts.aspx]

Comment: Have to say that the island is not too round...

Comment: @pbm but you could get 'round it pretty quick. There seems to be something of a fad for calling circularly-challenged islands 'round' - consider the example of Round Island, Mauritius - especially given its proximity to the more obviously circular 'Serpant Island' next door. More confusingly still, while Round Island is inundated with reptiles, Serpant Island has no snakes. But I digress...

Comment: Thank you so much for this info! I just moved to Clayton, NY, and this picture was left behind. I love it, even more now that I know its history. Thanks again!